# How to set up dns cache time?

Tags: networking, dns

Currently dns cache time on my ubuntu 17.10 is 300 seconds.

Using command:

```
dig +ttlid copyleaks.com
```

Gives me:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> +ttlid copyleaks.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 19394
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;copyleaks.com.                 IN      A
;; ANSWER SECTION:
copyleaks.com.          299     IN      A       104.24.29.22
copyleaks.com.          299     IN      A       104.24.28.22
;; Query time: 9 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Tue Apr 03 11:46:42 UTC 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 74
```

While after the domain you can see that its cached for 299 seconds and on subsequent queries its going down.

How can I set caching time to a different value?

Is there a way to set a value for a specific domain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every domain has timeouts defined in its SOA record (try `dig SOA copyleaks.com`). If you are the administrative authority for the domain, then you can setup the SOA record and setup your default cache times there. Then there are timeouts for each record, and I think this is the case in your example, where A record copyleaks.com (try `dig A copyleaks.com`) has a timeout of 300 seconds, which is different than timeout in SOA record. Every domain administrator sets the TTL (Time To Leave) times to a value that makes sure that DNS records are updated frequently enough and that they are not transferred too frequently from administrative servers.

For SOA record take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOA_record.
If you want to learn more about DNS I would recommend this http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100575.do.

Try your command for other domains and you will see different values.